# Extraction of elements from a website using similar method as favicon extraction -> http://www.google.com/s2/

Tags: google-sheets, web-scraping, xpath, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet

I've recently came across this function

```
=Arrayformula(image("http://www.google.com/s2/favicons?sz=64&domain="&A2:A))
```

That allows users to extract a favicon from a given website in column A using Google xml extraction system (I believe).

I was wondering if Google offers us similar tools to simply extract other elements from a given URL using Google Sheet?
For instance metadata, page title or other xml/html elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

take a dive into import functions:

- IMPORTHTML
- IMPORTXML
- IMPORTDATA
- IMPORTFEED
- IMPORTJSON (with script)

https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12188454?hl=en

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I've seen these functions in the past but didn't get to use them combined with other functions to extract things like metadata or page title for instance. Do you have by any chance some use cases /materials from stackoverflow or other websites that I could use to see how powerful this import functions can become combine with other ones?

Comment: @Damien, `IMPORTHTML` -> [Google documentation](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093339), [Blog](https://blog.coupler.io/importhtml-function-google-sheets/). `IMPORTXML` -> [Google documentation](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093342), [blog](https://blog.golayer.io/google-sheets/importxml-google-sheets). `IMPORTDATA` -> [Google documentation](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093335), [Blog](https://blog.coupler.io/importdata-google-sheets/).

Comment: `IMPORTFEED` -> [Google documentation](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093337), [Blog](https://productivityspot.com/importfeed-google-sheets/). `IMPORTJSON` ->[Blog](https://spreadsheetpoint.com/google-sheets-import-json-guide/)